# Why do I need brackets for simple expression?

Tags: php, brackets

Why do I need the brackets to add `$a + $b` below:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
function addNumbers(float $a, float $b) : int {
    return (int)($a + $b);
}
echo addNumbers(1.2, 5.2); 
?>
```

The used of brackets in cases like this confuses me. Why is an error thrown if the `$a + $b` isn't surrounded by brackets? It may be a simple question but study material often doesn't explain detail. Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: what syntax gives you error ?

Comment: because you wanna typecast the result of a + b and not just a

Comment: What this expression ```return (int)($a + $b);``` implies that you want to return an integer ```(int)``` which will be the product of $a+$b ```($a+$b)```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `()` around `$a + $b`, the code is interpreted as

```
return ((int)$a) + $b;
```

because the operator precedence of `(int)` is higher than that of `+` (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)) which in this case would be

```
((int)1.2) + 5.2
=>
1 + 5.2
=>
6.2
```

Even though the first value in this expression is an int, because the second is a floating point number, PHP will perform [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and convert the first value to a float as well, thus the result of the expression is a floating point number, which cannot be returned by `addNumbers` as it is declared to return an `int`.

By putting the `()` in, the expression is interpreted as

```
(int)(1.2+5.2)
=>
(int)6.4
=>
6
```

which is ok to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

As **kenzotenma** mentioned, "because you wanna typecast (int) the result of `$a + $b` and not just `$a`"

Try like below without bracket,

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
function addNumbers(float $a, float $b) : int {
    $result = $a + $b;
    return (int)$result ;
}
echo addNumbers(1.2, 5.2); 
?>
```

Comment: Ok. Thankyou everyone for your replies. The code snippet was from w3schools which doesn't always go into great detail. Is there a better online resource you can suggest for learning PHP from the ground up as I don't want to continue until I have a firm grasp on the fundamentals?

Comment: @trebleclef have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers